# upgrade configuration of less due to migrate rails from 3 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less-rails

Rails migration from v3 to v5 is in progress. Less loading is not worked.

```
couldn't find file '../less/style.less' under '{root}/app/assets/stylesheets' with type 'text/css'
```

(seems strange mime type in error message, I suppose may be `less` must be there)

actually file exists and all was worked before migration, bundle and code changes is performed according to documentation for migration process

also environment configured like this

```
config.less.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/less"
```

Any suggestions to figure out? Any additional request for debug/inspect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the file extension,

so instead:

```
*= require ../less/theme/style.less
```

is used:

```
*= require ../less/theme/style
```

and the problem disappears